# How to create a custom text editor in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, text-editor, netbeans-plugins

I've created a java based language plugin (netbeans module) in Netbeans IDE. But I want to use that plug-in with standalone text editor (java based). I want to create a standalone text editor which would edit files with extension *.abc and i want my plug-in(module) to work in that text editor.

Is there an easy way to create such a text editor and use that language module with that. Please advise on two things:
1. how can I create such a text editor?
2. How to use that language-auto-complete-functionality-plugin (netbeans module that I created) with the text editor created in point 1 above.